# Цикл WP с указанием метки постов

Tags: php, wordpress, циклы

В настройках виджета вывода постов для WP есть опция для указания меток записи. Переменная для нее назначается так: `$tags = $instance['tags'];` . В админке выводится так:

```
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id( 'tags' )); ?>">
        <?php _e('Метки:', 'site'); ?>
    </label>
    <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id( 'tags' )); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name( 'tags' )); ?>" value="<?php echo ($instance['tags']); ?>" style="width:100%;" />
</p>
```

Главное - `value="<?php echo ($instance['tags']); ?>".` В результате отображается строка для ввода id меток через запятую. В цикле используется такая конструкция для вывода постов:

```
$site_posts = new WP_Query(array( 'cat' => $categories, 'tag__in' => array($tags), 'posts_per_page' => $number, 'offset' => $paged_offset, 'paged'=>$paged ));
```

То есть используется `'tag__in' => array($tags)`, которая выводит записи если они принадлежат хотя бы одной из указанных меток. Почему-то если я в настройках указываю id нескольких меток через запятую, то выводятся посты, принадлежащие только к одной метке, указанной первой. Перепробовал много вариантов, но не работает ни один. Хотелось бы, чтобы выводились посты из всех указанных меток. Можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `$instance['tags']` - строка c id меток через запятую, то преобразовывать её в массив надо так:

```
$tags = explode( ',', $instance['tags'] );
```

и использовать так:

```
$site_posts = new WP_Query(array( 'cat' => $categories, 'tag__in' => $tags, 'posts_per_page' => $number, 'offset' => $paged_offset, 'paged'=>$paged ));
```

Comment: Я уже так делал с explode, но у меня ничего не вышло. А сейчас получилось, видимо где-то с синтаксисом напутал. А еще вопрос: как бы передать параметр отображения записей со всеми метками сразу?

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: А дополнительный ваш вопрос я не понимаю, попробуйте его сформулировать в новом вопросе отдельно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796053/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%82%D0%B5-wordpress-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC - вот  ссылка на новый вопрос