# Значение по умолчанию в видежте Wordpress по меткам

Tags: wordpress, циклы, виджет

Есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795980/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-wp-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), на который ответили. Новая проблема заключается в следующем. Если поле в настройках виджета для указания меток пусто, то в виджете не выводятся никакие статьи. Необходимо либо значение по умолчанию, которое бы выводило записи, содержащие все метки, либо условие, при котором при пустом поле выводились все записи со всеми метками.

`$tags = explode( ',', $instance['tags'] );` - переменная

`$site_posts = new WP_Query(array( 'cat' => $categories, 'tag__in' => $tags, 'posts_per_page'` - цикл

```
 <p>
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id( 'tags' )); ?>">
        <?php _e('Метки:', 'site'); ?>
    </label>
<input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id( 'tags' )); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name( 'tags' )); ?>" value="<?php echo ($instance['tags']); ?>" style="width:100%;" />
```

- настройка

В каком направлении копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь я понял, в чем вопрос. Я бы сделал так:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => $categories,
    'posts_per_page' => $number,
    'offset' => $paged_offset,
    'paged'=>$paged,
);
if ( '' !== $instance['tags'] ) {
    $tags = explode( ',', $instance['tags'] );
    $args['tag__in'] = $tags;
}

$site_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: KAGG Design - вы огненные молодцы!!! Рад, что живу с вами в одно время!

Comment: Однако не работает. Сначала показалось, что работает. Но не работает

Comment: Что именно не так?

Comment: Ничего не меняется. Посты не выводятся, если строка в настройках не заполнена. Ошибок нет

Comment: Поставил проверку на empty. Так должно работать.

Comment: с empty не фурычит тоже(

Comment: Еще раз исправил

Comment: Так заработало. Спасибо!